# Unity3d - Particles/Additive displays white instead of black

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

Particles/Additive on a `LineRenderer` displays white instead of black. Any idea what is the problem?

```
 Color edge_color=Color.black;
 edge_color.a = 0.7f;
 GameObject go = new GameObject ();
 var rend=go.AddComponent<LineRenderer> ();
 rend.useWorldSpace = false;
 rend.startWidth = 0.05f;
 rend.endWidth = 0.05f;
 rend.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Mobile/Particles/Additive"));
 rend.material.color = edge_color;
 //rend.SetPositions (...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by changing to Particles\Alpha blended shader. Also used startColor and endColor instead of material.color.
Still don't know why the additive shader won't show the color that I set using startColor and endColor (it becomes transparent after I set these two).